# even with the proper use of modernizr, opera is displaying multiple datepickers

Tags: html, datepicker, opera, modernizr

i have followed some tutorials and books to work with html5 **forms**.I used **modernizr** to provide a fallback for non supporting browsers. Everything is good. Things are even working in IE6. I am facing problem with jquery datepicker ui. currently **input type="date"** is supported only by opera(i am using the most latest version of opera).

---

Though i used **modernizr** for detecting browser support for **input type="date"**, somehow opera is still loading jquery datepicker. Am i doing anything wrong??... should i include scripts in specific order??...

---

This is the code i have written followed by screenshot of the problem.

***html markup:***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>date picker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="date" name="date-picker" id="date-picker" value="2010-10-06" />
</form>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="webforms/webforms2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***jquery code :***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!Modernizr.inputtypes.date){
        $('input[type=date]').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.datepicker({
            minDate: $input.attr('min'),
            maxDate: $input.attr('max'),
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
 }  
});
```

---

***screenshot:***

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/operadatepicker.jpg/

***source code:***[media fire download link](http://www.mediafire.com/?mx2nee934wf47ew)

Comment: ps you don't need the `.each`, that selector will already cover all the inputs. Interesting issue though so +1. (ie you could just use  `$('input[type=date]').datepicker({ .. });`

Comment: my bad. I just blindly followed several tutorials,which included same script... i will avoid it next time :)... i m following you in all possible social networks.... thanks for the catch ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Modernizr.inputtypes.date` works as expected in Opera 11:

http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/tMUcw/

Maybe the error is, that you haven't included 'Input Types' in you build of Modernizr. GO and download the developer version or build a custom download, but make sure to include 'Input Types'.

http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: hey thanks for the idea....actually till now i downloaded modernizr from the front page....now i will go with custom builds... things are solved now ... you pointed me in new direction :)